# How to make dependent cells follow decimal formatting of parent cell that changes from time to time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, formatting, conditional-formatting

I need dependent cells in an Excel worksheet to follow the decimal formatting of a parent cell. I've done this with format painter, but my parent cell decimal requirements change from time to time,
and I need the dependent cells to adjust and update accordingly.

Sometimes I might need to show no decimal places,
while other times I'll need to show one, or possibly two places.

In short, I want to change the decimal formatting of the parent cell and have this dictate the dependent cells on a per case basis.

Please see the following screenshots for examples of what I want to accomplish:
[image]

[image]

For illustration only, the parent cell is in red, dependent cells in yellow. 
I don't need anything other than the decimal formatting to be copied so color is not an issue.

Comment: You will need vba that copy and pastes the formatting and run it manually as neither vba nor formula will trigger on the change of format.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I found some help elsewhere and found a quick VBA to run.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You posed an interesting question that other people may also have.  If you found a solution, please consider posting an answer (sharing solutions to help others with a similar problem is what the site is all about).

Answer (score 0):

I understand you've found a VBA solution, it would be helpful for others if your shared it.

For others who prefer a non-VBA solution, `Conditional Format` easily handles Scenarios 1 and 3 and can likely be modified to for your specific needs. No VBA required.

Each scenario requires a conditional format.

Scenario 1: the formula is `=Int($F$2)-($F$2)=0` and the conditional number format is `Number` with 0 decimal places

Scenario 3: the formula is `=Int($F$2)-($F$2)<>0` and the conditional number format is `Number` with 2 decimal places

For both Scenarios: the fill color is yellow and the applies to range is `$B$4, $D$3, $D$4, $F$3, $F$4, etc`

Now, when `$F$2` contains an integer, the cells in the applied to range are formatted as integers and highlighted.  If `$F$2` is not an integer then the cells are are formatted to display 2 decimal places.